# Serve all content via HTTPS, regardless of web server settings

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssl, https

I've got a server running on port 80 on a Mac.

I'd like to also have the same content that's being served on port 80 available on port 443.

I'd like to know if there's a command line way or an easy to use tool that would let me take any non SSL port, encrypt it, and serve it up on an SSL encrypted port, *regardless of the server that's serving content on port 80*.

EDIT: I don't have control over the server configuration for what's serving content on port 80. But I'd like to see the same content served on port 443. How can I do this?

I suspect this can be done with SSH somehow (local port forwarding), but I haven't been able to find anything that seems to work.  I'm open to using any opensource tools to do this.... Apache, ssh, iptables.... whatever works!

Comment: Note that SSL, TLS and HTTPS have nothing to do with SSH.

Comment: I haven't done much port forwarding myself, but by SSH in this question I meant "on the server, use SSH to do a local port forward from port 80 to port 443". So the same content would be available on both ports. I thought this part would be possible, but getting it to encrypt correctly was the part that I wasn't sure about. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Using SSH to forward port 80 over port 443 won't make it use SSL/TLS or HTTPS. SSH is a *completely* different protocol from SSL/TLS, and HTTPS is HTTP over SSL/TLS. Pointing your browser via `https://` to port 443 on something that listens to SSH there will simply not work. (The fact that OpenSSH relies on OpenSSL doesn't mean that SSH relies on SSL, it's just than OpenSSL is a cryptography library that does far more than SSL/TLS.)

Comment: yeah i get that.... that's why I wrote "getting it to encrypt correctly was the part that I wasn't sure about." Thanks for your detailed response. I'm sure it'll add some value to the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could something in front of the server which translates from SSL to TCP, e.g. stunnel or similar software.

Comment: Yeah! This worked... Thanks.... I installed stunnel using "brew install stunnel", then I used this git repo for some sample scripts for using stunnel (https://github.com/mostlygeek/stunnel-ssl-proxy). Then I edited the stunnel.cnf and changed my ports to "accept = 443" and "connect = 80". Then to start the server, run "sudo ./start-server.sh"

Answer (score 1):

This is handled on the server side, not via port forwarding.  You just need to enable SSL, which will then let you get content via HTTPS on port 443.

Directions for how to do so for Apache:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: hey! thanks for the feedback... but I'm wondering if there's anyway to do it *regardless* of which server is being used.... So some way to server unencrypted port 80 traffic to port 443.... This would still be on the same server, but not configured per server. So for example, if I switched the backend to Lighttpd, it'd still work and content would still server on 443 without me having to figure out how to do it for Lighttpd.

Comment: Nope . . . the decision of what to serve is handled on the server side.  If your server isn't serving up HTTPS, then the client can't get HTTPS content . . .

Comment: I could run the program on the same machine.... that would be handled server side.... by some other server (eg nginx or apache)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using Apache and mod proxy.... I managed to do it using XAMPP, and the default httpd.conf that comes with XAMPP by including the following at the bottom of their "etc/httpd.conf" file

```
ServerName localhost

ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
   BalancerMember http://localhost route=myroute
</Proxy>

SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:HIGH:!ADH
```

*and* commenting out the last 2 lines of that file, the ones that

```
  # Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
  # Include "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"
```

*and* changing the default port apache was serving on from 80 to something else (e.g. 800)

```
Listen 800
```

I'm sure it can probably be done with less config than this, but this worked for me ;-)

Note: Optionally, if you want to make it so all http requests get rewritten to https (and you didn't do the Listen 800 line above), you can do the following using mod rewrite:

```
  # Rewrite all http requests to https
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```